# Excel PivotTable Remove Column Labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, dax

How do I remove the column labels so that I can create a PivotTable like the second example screenshot?

```
| title    | group  | tagKey    | tagValue |
| example1 | groupA | firstTag  |    foo   |
| example1 | groupA | secondTag |    bar   |
| example2 | groupB | firstTag  |    foo2  |
| example3 | groupA | firstTag  |    foo3  |
| example4 | groupC | firstTag  |    foo4  |
```

My pivot always adds (and splits) the columns into their labels, which is not my desired output.

First is my input table format. The lower table is how I want it to look. [table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87DXJ.png)

```
| title    | group  | firstTag | secondTag |
| example1 | groupA |   foo    |    bar    |
| example2 | groupB |   foo2   |           |
| example3 | groupA |   foo3   |           |
| example4 | groupC |   foo4   |           |
```

Edit: Deselecting View > Headings doesn't work. It gives this: [headings deselected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0XLf.png)

Edit #2: I almost have it, I just need to correct DAX formula now. I now have:

```
| Row Labels |  firstTag  |  secondTag |
|  example1  |     1      |      1     |
|  example2  |     1      |            |
|  example3  |     1      |            |
|  example4  |     1      |            |
```

Whereas I need the *textual value*, not the count.

I've tried creating a measure with the following DAX formulas:

- `=VALUES(Range[value])` (warning about single value expected)
- `=DISTINCT(Range[value])` (same warning as above)
- `=CONCATENATEX(Range, Range[value])` (doesn't drag to Values - no warning)

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

What you are looking to do is hide the row and column headers.  Please see the directions below.

1. Click on the View tab
2. Deselect the heading box

Hope that helps,
Brad